# Copy database tables from one database to another DB EF code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a database with two tables :

```
Employee       Salary
========      ================
Id Name        Id EmpId  Salary
```

and of course there is a class for each table to implement code first migration.

Is there any way to copy the database tables from the source database to another database and change the names of the tables using EF code-first?

PS: The target for this method is to create default database with default structure and when new client register create his own tables in existing database with new name

Comment: EF is *really NOT well suited* for large-scale, mass operations. Here, I'd say use straight SQL on your database to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to run code first against the database you are trying to copy the tables from (Add-> New Item -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code First from database.) Check off the tables you want to import. When you are done doing that delete the Entity DBContext and the connection string in your web.config. This will create all the models from the db you are trying to create. Add them to your model; Done.

```
public DbSet<StudentsModel> MyNewTable{ get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     modelBuilder.Entity<MyNewTable>().ToTable("MyTable");
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case Entity framework layer code will differ from client to client?
Since you will have some more table on one client than another one.
You can change the name by 
modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("mytesttablename");  fluent API
OR table attribute
[Table("mytesttablename")]
public class test 
{
}
etc

Comment: Ok , But how i can copy these tables ? from one context to another context